# Como gravar o valor com casas decimais antes do ponto no sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

Tenho um campo no banco com este formato

```
TESTE   numeric(8, 3)
```

Quero gravar desta formar.

```
UPDATE TB_PLANO_CONTAS SET TESTE = 001.000 WHERE  IDPLANOCONTAS = 63
```

O resultado esta ficando assim: **1.000**

```
UPDATE TB_PLANO_CONTAS SET TESTE = 101.000 WHERE  IDPLANOCONTAS = 64
```

O resultado esta ficando assim: **101.000**

Comment: O sql ignora os zeros a esquerda.

Comment: Qual o motivo de você precisar fazer isso? Qualquer campo numérico ingorará os zeros à esquerda. De qualquer maneira, me parece que o valor que você precisa gravar não é um número, mas uma espécie de conta contábil. Se for isso, então você deve mudar o campo para String, pois é o que faz sentido para o seu problema.

Comment: Todos ignoram zeros a esquerda de um valor.

Answer (score 1):

Este problema está ocorrendo porque o campo criado no SQL é numérico. Sendo assim, os zeros a esquerda são ignorados. Mesmo você fazendo um loop pra inserir os zeros, não conseguirá.

Uma forma de fazer isso é alterar o campo de numérico para caractere, mas ai vc tem que ver sua necessidade do tipo do campo.